# Angular - Data don't stay when reloading the page

Tags: angular, firebase, reload

I'm a bit new to angular and there is something i don't understand. I hope you'll be able to help me.

I'm building an app with Angular and Firebase which include a signup page.
When i submit the signup form everything goes well and data are sent to Firebase:
[Data stored in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7bsj.png)

And then the app goes to a page that displays the users list. The new user is there as planed.

The thing is when i reload the list is empty but data are still in Firebase.

Here is the code for the userlist component (the one which displays users):

```js
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 
  users: User[];
  userSubscription: Subscription;
 
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userSubscription = this.userService.userSubject.subscribe(
      (users: User[]) => {
        this.users = users;
      }
    );
    this.userService.emitUsers();
  }
 
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.userSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
 
}
```

And here is the code for the userService (the one which get data from Firebase):

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private users: User[] = [
      new User('admin', 'admin', 'email@gmail.com')
  ];
  userSubject = new Subject<User[]>();
 
  emitUsers() {
    this.userSubject.next(this.users.slice());
  }
 
  addUser(user: User) {
    this.users.push(user);
    this.emitUsers();
  }
 
  saveUsersToServer() {
    this.httpClient
      .put('https://TEST.firebaseio.com/users.json', this.users)
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          console.log('Enregistrement terminé !');
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('Erreur : ' + error);
        }
       );
  }
 
  getUsersFromServer() {
    this.httpClient
      .get<any[]>('https://TEST.firebaseio.com/users.json')
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.users = response;
          this.emitUsers();
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('Erreur ! : ' + error);
        }
      );
  }
 
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
 
}
```

I did not show the imports since there is no bug with it.

Did i misunderstood something about Angular fundamentals?
Is it normal to loose data when reloading the page?

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Olivier, for the futur, hide your URL. I can fetch all your users info. [{"email":"olivier.berton133@gmail.com","login":"admin","password":"admin"},{"email":"toto@gmail.com","login":"toto","password":"toto"}]

PS: Use angularFire2 it will save you a lot of time!

npm install -s angularfire2

Comment: Thank you for the advice, at least only the email address is real.

Comment: Why are you "reloading" the page in the first place?

Comment: To see what it does if the user does it.

Comment: If you want to persist data between page refreshes Go for `LocalStorage` or `sessionStorage`

Comment: But what if i got a lot to store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And then the app goes to a page that displays the users list.

In this component on `ngOnInit()` call your services `getUsersFromServer()` That way when ever someone reloads that page, `getUsersFromServer()` will be called and you will get your users list.